# A quoi pourrait correspondre "Babbitt" en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Peut-être "beauf" ou "français moyen" mais, il me semble, que le terme est plus étendu. 
Une idée ?

D'après [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babbitt_%28novel%29) suite au succès du livre du même nom, "Babbit" est entré dans le langage anglais: "une personne, et en particulier un homme d'affaires, ou un professionnel qui se conforme sans réfléchir aux standards des classes moyennes"

Il s'agit d'une catégorisation sociale, du genre de ce qu'on appelle les "bluenoses" (les nez bleus) qui désignent les moralistes ou puritains.

Comment: Babitt est un nom propre, une référence littéraire, et de la littérature anglo-saxone. La question posée n'est pas à proprement parler une question de langue française.

Comment: Peut-être avec un peu plus de contexte il serait plus facile de trouver une réponse?

Comment: Question très mal posée. La seule question acceptable serait de savoir quel personnage de la littérature française correspond le mieux au personnage de Babitt (Sinclair Lewis), mais est-ce une question de langue française ? Si la question est de savoir ce que représente le personnage de Babbitt, ce n'est pas ici qu'il faut la poser.

Comment: @M'vy j'ai updaté ma question

Comment: Dans la littérature anglaise Babbitt est souvent qualifié de philistin plutôt que de puritain (*bluenose* est très peu employé). Mais on ne traduirait pas Babbitt, qui est toujours une référence au personnage de Lewis, tout comme en anglais gavroche (même sans majuscule) reste gavroche et une référence au roman de Hugo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Philistin me semble bien, pour suivre Laure.

Sinon, on peut penser à Monsieur Prudhomme chez Henri Monnier, ou Monsieur Homais chez Flaubert. C'est un peu l'archétype du bourgeois, en somme.

Comment: J'aime bien le M. Homais.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two suggestions in the form of [song titles](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/jacques-brel-lyrics.html) taken from my favorite poet/songwriter/singer:

1-  “[Les moutons](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/les-moutons-sheep.html)” by Jacques Brel

2-  "[Les Bourgeois](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/les-bourgeois-burgeois-middle-class.html)"  (also by the “Grand Jacques”)

And for a song/song title that confirms my agreement with the accepted answer:

“[Les Philistins](http://www.analysebrassens.com/?page=texte&id=46&masquerAnalyses=0)” by Georges Brassens